# `require` hooks in a node package

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm building a node package that has some es6 code in it so I want to
hot load es6 code with `babel`.

In my `index.js` I put:

```
require('babel/register'); // register es6 transpolar for all following requires

module.exports = {
  foo: require('lib/foo')
, bar: require('lib/bar')
}
```

`lib/foo` contains es6 code so needs the babel require hook to function properly.

This makes `index.js` work properly when used inside this library (`node index.js` works, as well as test etc). But as soon as I use the project as a dependency in another project the require hook fails to work and I get syntax errors because of es6 syntax.

How can I make the registered hook work even when the project is a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to be some problem related to `require()` caching, but regardless of the cause, **YOU SHOULD NOT USE BABEL/REGISTER IN A REQUIRED LIBRARY**.

From [Babel documentation](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/):

> ### Not suitable for libraries
>
> The require hook automatically hooks itself into all node requires. This will pollute the global scope and introduce conflicts. Because of this it's not suitable for libraries, if however you're writing an application then it's completely fine to use.

Comment: you can "npm link" the dependency - it will be transpiled in this case.
babel require hook has to be called from the main project (assuming it is needed for the main project too), not in dependency. In the dependency the hook can be called from the test. you can support the issue: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1110 :)